# How to dynamically add html elements with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

My goal is to have one element on initial load, this element should have id="something_**O**", when a add link is clicked, underneath already existing element, new, the same html element should be added,not with id="something_o", but with id="something_**1**", or last element *+ 1*, to be specific. The user should be able to add these elements infinitely. When the user clicks deleted, element should disappear.

[image: Example of this case]

Any ideas?
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ingol/QeSPP/) is prepared fiddle for easier help...

Comment: @DennisTraub, I have trouble from the start, how to generate elements...

Comment: ref: http://api.jquery.com/clone/  And, could you explain why you want to maintain the counted ids? I don't really see a use for that for using them with css would mean you'd need every possible id before-hand.

Comment: @Yoshi, thanks , I need id's for extracting data later on, the css id's dont need to be id's, could be class. I take a look at he clone().

Comment: How would you use such an id? You could simply use the elements index (position in it's parent element), which would be exactly the numbering you try to achieve (and you wouldn't even have to maintain it).

Comment: @Yoshi, I need id's for extracting values from graph that is located in this div, so i can pass params to mvc controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var counter = 1;
$('.AddEl').live('click', function () {
    var el = $('#element_1').clone().attr('id', 'element_' + ++counter).appendTo('body');
});

$('.RemoveEl').live('click', function () {
    var el = $(this).parents('.elem')
    if (el.get(0).id !== 'element_1') el.remove();
});
```

[Check this here](http://jsfiddle.net/QeSPP/29/)

Comment: Thanks, element_0 should be removable, there always must be one element, not necesary element_0??

Comment: I mean, first[0] element sholud be removable, in your example it canot be removed?

Comment: Something like this:  $(this).closest('.actions').parent().remove(); but that one element always stays??

Comment: That is because I've used `element_1` to create clones. Do you want me to modify the code?

Comment: yes, but one element should remaine, not depended on Id_number

Answer (score 3):

One means to do this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.AddEl', function() {
        $('.actions:first')
            .parent()
            .clone()
            .attr('id', 'element_' + $('.actions').length)
            .insertAfter($('.actions:last').parent());
    });
    $('body').on('click', '.RemoveEl', function() {
        $(this).closest('.actions').parent().remove();
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QeSPP/26/).

Please note that I've amended your html so that the first element to be cloned is now `id="element_0"`, and targeted that, and all subsequently-created elements, with the CSS selector:

```
div[id^=element] {
    /* css */
}
```

This could be simplified, but these are simply my first thoughts.

---

**Edited** to offer a slightly improved version, in that the initial addition is slightly, or seems a little, more concise, and also features a means to prevent duplicate `id`s being generated if elements are added/removed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.AddEl', function() {
        var $elems = $('.actions').parent();
        $elems
            .first()
            .clone()
            .insertAfter($elems.last());
        $('div[id^="element_"]').each(
            function(i){
                $(this).attr('id','element_' + i);
            });
    });
    $('body').on('click', '.RemoveEl', function() {
        $(this).closest('.actions').parent().remove();
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QeSPP/36/).

Comment: If he wanted to keep the enumeration starting with 1, he could just add a +1 to this line:
`.attr('id', 'element_' + $('.actions').length+1)`

Comment: He could, but it seems a little needless, and I should edit in an amendment to make sure that, on deletion and addition, a duplicate id isn't created...

Answer (score 1):

I just overwrite to your code.

You can try this, may something you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/kongkannika/QeSPP/34/